# Failed to receive heartbeat from agent

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm try to install cloudera over Ubuntu 14.04.
I get an error message during adding a new cluster node.

```
Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
If Use TLS Encryption for Agents is enabled in Cloudera Manager (Administration -> Settings -> Security), ensure that /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini has use_tls=1 on the host being added. Restart the corresponding agent and click the Retry link here.
```

[image]

please helppppppppp

Comment: I'm too face this problem,Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Install NTP server. Configure /etc/ntp.conf with time server details. Then start ntpd service and add it to startup

Comment: I have install and configure but the problem does not solved.

Comment: Have you started the ntpd service